# ClassCastException when inputing value to list

Tags: java, classcastexception

I want to add a value in my List.

```
    for (int i=0; i<bookId.length;i++) {
        this.author.setBookList((List<Book>) this.bookBean.retrieveBook(bookId[i]));
    }
```

but i got an exception.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: business.model.Book cannot be
>   cast to java.util.List at
>   presentation.control.AuthorBean.createAuthor(AuthorBean.java:68) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

I want to know, how to make my join table list type and input type the same ?

Comment: Well the error message says you are asigning a book when it expects a list. Clearly your this.bookBean.retrieveBook(bookId[i]) is returning a single book rather than a list. Change that function.

Comment: @e4c5 thx for commenting, but i put (List<Book>) at the beggining so my fuction can return as a list but it cant change to list. As i said, i want to know how to change my type of input so it can be the same as my join table.

Comment: What are you saying? You can't just force one type of object into something completely unrelated by the mere use of a cast '(List<Book>)' you will have to fix that before you can get anywhere

Comment: @e4c5 okay, ill try another method for getting the list. Thx for the sugesstion.

Comment: Anytime you get an exception of `java.lang.*` package, you have a basic Java SE problem, not a general Java EE problem. So please don't tag question with `[java-ee]` and such. I fixed the wrong tags and removed irrelevant code from the question.

Comment: @BalusC Okay, ill be careful next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a new List before you enter your loop. 
Within the loop retrieve the single book and *add* it to the existing List. 
After the loop, assign the list to the author.

```
    // ...
    List<Book> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<bookId.length;i++) {
        list.add(this.bookBean.retrieveBook(bookId[i]));
    }       
    author.setBookList(list);        
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, it works for me!!! i really really really apreciate it ^0^.

Comment: You're welcome!: ) ..... PS: related to BalusC's comment on the original question, I removed the unrelated parts of code in my answer too.